Find all integers $n$ such that $2n^4+1$ is a perfect square.
I have the following problem:
Find all integers $n$ such that $$2n^4+1$$ is a perfect square.
I experimented a bit with values for $n$, leading to the conjecture that only $n=0$ is a solution. But I do not have any idea how to prove that.
Because of the 1, Pell's Equation came to my mind, but I could not show that $n$ is not an integer solution then.
I would be very thankful for hints or the solution.
Thank you very much in advance.

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1567238p9602823

@BoweiTang This link is dealing with prime number, not perfect square.
